# How to refer to the current record in a Rails query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails controller I'm using a JSON request to an external database to return integers that are used to order a collection of records:

```
Model.order(JSON.parse(open("http://myapp.com/models/#{:id}")).read)['attribute'])
```

I want to make this dynamic to aid switching between environments. Something like:

```
Model.order(JSON.parse(open(model_url(model))).read)['attribute'])
```

This is not correct, and `model_url(model)` is returning an error:

`undefined local variable or method 'model'`

How do I refer to self in query?

There must be a more elegant solution than

```
...JSON.parse(open("#{root_url}/models/{:id}"))....
```

EDIT:

Lightswitch05's answer below does anser the question I asked. The query should reference `params[:id]` to get the url of the current record.

In fact, I have decided to move this JSON call into a virtual attribute on the model. This means I can simply call `Model.order(:my_virtual_attribute)`. While this solution brings its own share of issues—I needed to make url_helpers available to the model—in the long run I think this will be a cleaner solution.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: Can you supply a snippet of "view" code that sends back to the controller what you want?

Comment: hi @thisfeller, the view code will not be of any use. Its simply an index view. But I need to get the order of records from an external JSON request

Comment: So, all you are trying to get from the external API request is a ID for the model? Do you not already the model ID to make the external request to begin with?

Comment: @giorgan, I'm trying to refer to the current record in a query. Basically I want to know how to achieve `Model.order(model_url(model))`. And I know that this makes no sense on its own, but everything else will simply detract from the real question.

Comment: @lightswitch05, no its not an ID I need. I need to order records in one database, based on values of related records in a second database. Basically I'm accessing an attribute from an external data source. But this is overcomplicating my issue. All I need to know is how to refer to `self` within an order query, i.e., `Model.order(model)`

Comment: Is the order variable? `Model.order("some_col DESC")` would set the order. If its variable, then you are going to have to have another function to determine the order your json object is in, as `Model.order` can't magically figure out the ordering of any list of items

Comment: the json call returns an integer for each record on which the order can be established. It works if I hard code the external url. I need (want) to make the url dynamic to aid switching between environments. Hence being able to use the path helpers in the order statement would be very useful

Comment: Ok, so `model` is undefined. Can your share your current URL context and the results of `bundle exec rake routes`? Could it perhaps be `params[:model]` instead of just `model`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29543/discussion-between-lightswitch05-and-andy-harvey)

Comment: I've updated my question which hopefully explains more clearly what I wan to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29543/discussion-between-lightswitch05-and-andy-harvey) the problem is that `model` is not defined. Since all you are trying to do with `model` is get the url to it, all you really need is `params[:id]`. This will fix your error message:

```
Model.order(JSON.parse(open(model_url(params[:id]))).read)['attribute'])
```

where `model` has been replaced with `params[:id]`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code:

```
Model.order(JSON.parse(open(model_url(model))).read)['attribute'])
```

to:

```
model_tableized = Model.to_s.tableize
model_url = "#{model_tableized}_url(#{model_tableized.chomp('s')})"
Model.order(JSON.parse(open(model_url).read)["attribute"])
```

I think that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `name` method.

If you're using the model, and not an instance of the model, it would be `Model.name`

If you're using an instance, it would be

```
@model = Model.first
@model.class.name
```